# SQL function for IFNULL with three params?

Tags: sql

I am aware of the sql function that will change the value of an item if that item is null:

```
IFNULL(val, "was null")
```

Is there a way to change the value if it is null, and **also** change it if it is not null? In other words, it would be a shorthand for:

```
IF(val IS NULL, "was null", "was not null")
-->
IFNULL(val, "was null", "was not null")
```

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: @diiN__________ it was more a db-agnostic question, I'll use mysql or postgres or sqlserver or bigquery usually.

Comment: Something like this? CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN 'was null' ELSE 'was not null' END

Comment: For sql server you'd have `IIF(condition, [value if true], [value if false])`

Comment: Built-in functions - such as [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull) - are **not** _db-agnostic_. Hence if you ask specifically about `IFNULL` that means you are using MySQL.

Comment: @Abra `IFNULL` is included in [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions), [Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ifnull), [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html), [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/NVL.html), but yes it's not always named `IFNULL`.

Comment: _but yes it's not always named `IFNULL`_ So how am I meant to know that when you ask about `IFNULL` you are also referring to `nvl` in Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic ANSI SQL way of doing this would be to simply use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE WHEN val IS NULL THEN 'was null' ELSE 'was not null' END AS label
```

On some databases, such as MySQL, there is a formal `IF()` function which works exactly as you described in your question:

```sql
-- from MySQL
IF(val IS NULL, 'was null', 'was not null') AS label
```

Answer (score 1):

In MSSQL Server you could use the [IIF Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_iif.asp)

```
 SELECT IIF(val is null, 'YES', 'NO');
```